# Coordinate geometry - move a line $X$ units along its normal

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

So I have a straight line, in the classic $y = mx + b$, and I'm just trying to translate the formula for the line a certain distance along its normal.

For example, with [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8vct.jpg), how would I translate the red line to the blue one if (for example) $x$ was $4$?

Comment: The so-called "normal form" of the equation of a line makes this very easy.  Note that the line could move in either of two directions (keeping the same slope of course) to get $4$ units away from its original position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line $ y = mx + b $ has a slope $ \tan \phi =m $. It should be parallelly displaced through distance $d$.

The $y$ intercept increases or decreases by an amount

$$ d \sec \phi = d\, \sqrt{1+m^2}$$

so that the displaced line is

$$ y = mx + b \pm d\, \sqrt{1+m^2}. $$

PS: Please avoid using same symbol $X$ in the graph used for a variable of the straight line.

Comment: That appears to be correct! Thank you _so much_, Narashimham, that was driving me crazy

Comment: You are Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the equation of your first line is

$$y=mx+b.$$

Then the angle this line makes to the $x$-axis is $\arctan (m)$. Then the angle perpendicular to this in the direction wanted is $\arctan (m) - \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then by trigonometry, the amount required to translate the $y$-intercept of line is $4\sin (\arctan (m) - \frac{\pi}{2}).$

Hence the translated line will be

$$y=mx+b+4\sin\Big(\arctan (m)-\frac{\pi}{2}\Big).$$

Comment: Hey cws, thanks so much for that! Doesn't quite seem to work for me, though. 

I've written it into a function like so (which, given any X, will return the Y value from the new line):
var y = m * x + b + translationDistance * Math.Sin(Math.Atan(m) - (Math.PI / 2));

which I think is pretty much exactly what was written, but some part of the calculation seems off (https://imgur.com/a/8lkmz). 

I don't suppose you can immediately see anything wrong with the above? I can confirm m and b are correct, so it seems isolated to the above function.

Comment: I think:- 1) The y-intercept might be $\dfrac {4}{\sin (arctan (m) - \dfrac {\pi}{2})}$ instead; 2) The target line is to be moved 'downward', I am not sure whether the denominator can generate a negative sign or not.

Comment: Ahh, didn't quite seem to work but thanks for your help anyways, @Mick!